# How to show a specific page on clicking a notification in a project that works with Android and cordova?

Tags: javascript, android, push-notification, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

I am using **cordova 3.3.1** in my project.

I intend to display my notifications in my status bar notification in android devices. In order to implement that I manipulated **createNotification()** function in **GCMIntentService** class, and now I recieve the notifications.

Now I am going to show a specific page when I click on the notifications (It depends to notification type). Do you have any idea about it, i don't know how implement    this part?
    I just know that if I modify my java class which extend CordovaActivity, then whenever
    I run "cordova build" command, I'll lose all the codes because this class will be genarated by
    cordova.  Here comes my code:

```
  --------------in my class GCMIntentService---------------------------
    public void createNotification(Context context, Bundle extras)
{   

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String appName = getAppName(this);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, G3Tracker.class);
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("pushBundle", extras);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setSmallIcon(context.getApplicationInfo().icon)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentTitle(extras.getString("title"))
            .setTicker(extras.getString("title"))
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    String message = extras.getString("message");
    if (message != null) {
        mBuilder.setContentText("You recieved a new notification: " + message);

    } else {
        mBuilder.setContentText("message");

    }

 ----------------------------------------------------- 
            public class G3Tracker extends CordovaActivity 
 {
      @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         super.init();
      // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
         super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
       //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html")
   }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notif = new Notification(com.project.R.drawable.app_icon, "heading title", System.currentTimeMillis());
CharSequence from = "application name";
CharSequence message = "message which you want to show";
intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this,ShowActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("NotifID", notifID);
pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getActivity(MyActivity.this, notifID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT| PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
notif.setLatestEventInfo(this, from, message, intent);
notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notif.vibrate = new long[] { 100, 250, 100, 500 };
nm.notify(notifID, notif);
finish();
```

Try this code it works for me, if you have any query then reply me.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but where do you define your destination?

Comment: intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this,ShowActivity.class);